# Pandas split and replace string value in a column and create binary encoded columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, binary

I have the following list of values per row. I would like to split these values into separate categories and create separate columns.

Some of these values belong to the same category. So I need to categorise them in columns

```
0, Body;TSS1500
1, TSS200
2,
3, 1stExon;3'UTR
4,
5, TSS200;TSS200;TSS200
6, 1stExon;3'UTR
7, TSS1500
8, 1stExon;5'UTR
9, TSS200
10, 5'UTR;1stExon
11, TSS200;TSS200;TSS200
12, TSS1500;1stExon;TSS1500;5'UTR
```

Expected output

```
   Body  TSS   UTR   Other
0, 1     1     0      0
1, 0     1     0      0
2, 0     0     0      0 
3, 0     0     0      1
4, 0     0     0      0
5, 0     1     0      0
6, 0     0     1      1
...
```

I know I can use `pd.get_dummies(df.regions.explode()).sum(level=0)` However, my issue is that values need to be split (if substring matches) and categorized. e.g. 3'UTR and 5'UTR = UTR, and TSS200, TSS1500 = TSS.

It could be that I have an unknown prefix/suffix associated with a string. However, each categorical values are delimited by `;`

So I am kinda lost on how to combine these different operations.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Values": [
            "Body;TSS1500",
            "TSS200",
            "1stExon;3'UTR",
            "TSS200;TSS200;TSS200",
            "1stExon;3'UTR",
            "TSS1500",
            "1stExon;5'UTR",
            "TSS200",
            "5'UTR;1stExon",
            "TSS200;TSS200;TSS200",
            "TSS1500;1stExon;TSS1500;5'UTR",
        ]
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
def func(string, str_list):
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        string: target string.
        str_list: list of strings to look for.

    Returns:
        1 if target string contains one or more string in str_list else 0.

    """
    res = []
    for substring in string.split(";"):
        sub_res = []
        for other_val in str_list:
            if other_val in substring:
                sub_res.append(other_val)
        if not any(sub_res):
            res.append(substring)
    return 1 if res else 0
```

Then:

```py
str_list = ["Body", "TSS", "UTR"]

for val in str_list:
    df[val] = df["Values"].str.contains(val).astype(int)

df["Other"] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x["Values"], str_list), axis=1)
```

And so:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                           Values  Body  TSS  UTR  Other
0                    Body;TSS1500     1    1    0      0
1                          TSS200     0    1    0      0
2                   1stExon;3'UTR     0    0    1      1
3            TSS200;TSS200;TSS200     0    1    0      0
4                   1stExon;3'UTR     0    0    1      1
5                         TSS1500     0    1    0      0
6                   1stExon;5'UTR     0    0    1      1
7                          TSS200     0    1    0      0
8                   5'UTR;1stExon     0    0    1      1
9            TSS200;TSS200;TSS200     0    1    0      0
10  TSS1500;1stExon;TSS1500;5'UTR     0    1    1      1
```